# window.close() is not a function in electron What I am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Here is my code [Github repo url](https://github.com/imanaspaul/electron-helloworld)

```js
const {app, Menu, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const mainWindow = require("./windows/mainWindow");

// Catching events from clients
ipcMain.on("login", ()=>{
  dashboardWindow();
  mainWindow.close();
})
```

`./windows/mainWindow` file:

```
// Initialize main window
const mainWindow = () => {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      webPreferences: {
                  nodeIntegration: true
                      }
    });
  // Load html in window
  mainWindow.loadFile("./templates/index.html")
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
}

module.exports = mainWindow;
```

How could I close a window?

Answer (score 3):

`mainWindow` is a function, so you need to call it and inside the function also return the window:

```js
const {app, Menu, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const mainWindowFunc = require("./windows/mainWindow");

const mainWindow = mainWindowFunc(); // <-- Call function

ipcMain.on("login", ()=>{
  dashboardWindow();
  mainWindow.close();  // <-- Now close should be available, because you call it on the instance of BrowserWindow
})
```

`./windows/mainWindow` file:

```
const mainWindow = () => {
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      webPreferences: {
                  nodeIntegration: true
                      }
    });

  mainWindow.loadFile("./templates/index.html")
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  return mainWindow; // <-- return window
}

module.exports = mainWindow;
```

Comment: It's not giving me the error, but the main window is not closing, it behaves like it's closed but it's still there underneath the dashboard window

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171597/atom-electron-close-the-window-with-javascript. If not please open a new question with your new problem. @ManasPaul

Comment: Also, maybe look here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11790 Don't know if that's the issue though.

Comment: You could also try to call `.destroy()` on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937111/electron-close-button-not-working @ManasPaul

Comment: No problem - feel free to accept my answer then @ManasPaul